# How to install pygraphviz using conda or pip on Python 3.6?

Tags: python, pip, clang, graphviz, pygraphviz

I am not sure what to do here but I really need to use the `graphviz` layouts with `networkx`.

I was doing it the way specific by the installation process of when `graphviz` can't be found:

> Your Graphviz installation could not be found.
>
> ```
>         1) You don't have Graphviz installed:
>            Install Graphviz (http://graphviz.org)
>
>         2) Your Graphviz package might incomplete.
>            Install the binary development subpackage (e.g. libgraphviz-dev or similar.)
>
>         3) You are using Windows
>            There are no PyGraphviz binary packages for Windows but you might be
>            able to build it from this source.  See
>            http://networkx.lanl.gov/pygraphviz/reference/faq.html
>
>         If you think your installation is correct you will need to manually
>         provide path to graphviz include and library. For example:
>
>         pip install pygraphviz --install-option="--include-path=/usr/include/graphviz" --install-option="--library-path=/usr/lib/graphviz/"
>
>         The current setting of library_dirs and include_dirs is:
> library_dirs=None
> include_dirs=None
>
> error: Error locating graphviz.
> ```

Here's my `python` version:

```
(py3_testing) jespinozlt-osx:~ jespinoz$ python
Python 3.6.4 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Jan 16 2018, 12:04:33)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Clang 4.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_401/final)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

Here's my `OS` version on my `Mac`:

```
(py3_testing) jespinozlt-osx:~ jespinoz$ sw_vers
ProductName:    Mac OS X
ProductVersion: 10.11.6
BuildVersion:   15G1217
```

I made sure that `graphviz` is installed:

```
(py3_testing) jespinozlt-osx:~ jespinoz$ ls -l ~/anaconda/envs/py3_testing/include/| grep "graphviz"
drwxr-xr-x   29 jespinoz  tigr     986 Jun  6 12:51 graphviz
(py3_testing) jespinozlt-osx:~ jespinoz$ ls -l ~/anaconda/envs/py3_testing/lib/| grep "graphviz"
drwxr-xr-x   18 jespinoz  tigr       612 Jun  6 12:51 graphviz
```

Now when I try to install via `pip`:

```
(py3_testing) jespinozlt-osx:~ jespinoz$ pip install pygraphviz --install-option="--include-path=~/anaconda/envs/py3_testing/include/graphviz/" --install-option="--library-path=~/anaconda/envs/py3_testing/lib/graphviz"
/Users/jespinoz/anaconda/envs/py3_testing/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py:194: UserWarning: Disabling all use of wheels due to the use of --build-options / --global-options / --install-options.
  cmdoptions.check_install_build_global(options)
Collecting pygraphviz
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/98/bb/a32e33f7665b921c926209305dde66fe41003a4ad934b10efb7c1211a419/pygraphviz-1.3.1.tar.gz
Skipping bdist_wheel for pygraphviz, due to binaries being disabled for it.
Installing collected packages: pygraphviz
  Running setup.py install for pygraphviz ... error
    Complete output from command /Users/jespinoz/anaconda/envs/py3_testing/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/6z/5vbtz_gmkr76ftgc3149dvtr0003c0/T/pip-build-_hho1hi2/pygraphviz/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/6z/5vbtz_gmkr76ftgc3149dvtr0003c0/T/pip-v2gpw_h3-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --include-path=~/anaconda/envs/py3_testing/include/graphviz/ --library-path=~/anaconda/envs/py3_testing/lib/graphviz:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/pygraphviz
    copying pygraphviz/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/pygraphviz
    copying pygraphviz/agraph.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/pygraphviz
    copying pygraphviz/graphviz.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/pygraphviz
    copying pygraphviz/release.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/pygraphviz
    copying pygraphviz/version.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/pygraphviz
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/pygraphviz/tests
    copying pygraphviz/tests/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/pygraphviz/tests
    copying pygraphviz/tests/test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/pygraphviz/tests
    copying pygraphviz/tests/test_attribute_defaults.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/pygraphviz/tests
    copying pygraphviz/tests/test_attributes.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/pygraphviz/tests
    copying pygraphviz/tests/test_clear.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/pygraphviz/tests
    copying pygraphviz/tests/test_drawing.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/pygraphviz/tests
    copying pygraphviz/tests/test_edge_attributes.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/pygraphviz/tests
    copying pygraphviz/tests/test_graph.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/pygraphviz/tests
    copying pygraphviz/tests/test_html.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/pygraphviz/tests
    copying pygraphviz/tests/test_layout.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/pygraphviz/tests
    copying pygraphviz/tests/test_node_attributes.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/pygraphviz/tests
    copying pygraphviz/tests/test_readwrite.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/pygraphviz/tests
    copying pygraphviz/tests/test_string.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/pygraphviz/tests
    copying pygraphviz/tests/test_subgraph.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/pygraphviz/tests
    copying pygraphviz/tests/test_unicode.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/pygraphviz/tests
    running egg_info
    writing pygraphviz.egg-info/PKG-INFO
    writing dependency_links to pygraphviz.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
    writing top-level names to pygraphviz.egg-info/top_level.txt
    reading manifest file 'pygraphviz.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*~' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '.svn' found anywhere in distribution
    no previously-included directories found matching 'doc/build'
    writing manifest file 'pygraphviz.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    copying pygraphviz/graphviz.i -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/pygraphviz
    copying pygraphviz/graphviz_wrap.c -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/pygraphviz
    running build_ext
    building 'pygraphviz._graphviz' extension
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/pygraphviz
    x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang -DNDEBUG -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -march=core2 -mtune=haswell -mssse3 -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fPIE -fstack-protector-strong -O2 -pipe -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -mmacosx-version-min=10.9 -I~/anaconda/envs/py3_testing/include/graphviz/ -I/Users/jespinoz/anaconda/envs/py3_testing/include/python3.6m -c pygraphviz/graphviz_wrap.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/pygraphviz/graphviz_wrap.o
    pygraphviz/graphviz_wrap.c:2954:10: fatal error: 'graphviz/cgraph.h' file not found
    #include "graphviz/cgraph.h"
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    1 error generated.
    error: command 'x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/Users/jespinoz/anaconda/envs/py3_testing/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/6z/5vbtz_gmkr76ftgc3149dvtr0003c0/T/pip-build-_hho1hi2/pygraphviz/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/6z/5vbtz_gmkr76ftgc3149dvtr0003c0/T/pip-v2gpw_h3-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --include-path=~/anaconda/envs/py3_testing/include/graphviz/ --library-path=~/anaconda/envs/py3_testing/lib/graphviz" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/6z/5vbtz_gmkr76ftgc3149dvtr0003c0/T/pip-build-_hho1hi2/pygraphviz/
```

I installed with Homebrew:

```
(python3) jespinozlt-osx:anaconda jespinoz$ ls /usr/local/Cellar/graphviz/2.40.1/include/graphviz/
(python3) jespinozlt-osx:anaconda jespinoz$ ls /usr/local/Cellar/graphviz/2.40.1/lib/
graphviz/             libcdt.dylib          libcgraph.dylib       libgvc.dylib          libgvpr.dylib         liblab_gamut.dylib    libpathplan.dylib     libxdot.dylib
libcdt.5.dylib        libcgraph.6.dylib     libgvc.6.dylib        libgvpr.2.dylib       liblab_gamut.1.dylib  libpathplan.4.dylib   libxdot.4.dylib       pkgconfig/
(python3) jespinozlt-osx:anaconda jespinoz$ ls /usr/local/Cellar/graphviz/2.40.1/lib/graphviz/
config6                 libgvplugin_core.dylib          libgvplugin_dot_layout.dylib        libgvplugin_gd.dylib            libgvplugin_neato_layout.dylib      libgvplugin_quartz.dylib
libgvplugin_core.6.dylib        libgvplugin_dot_layout.6.dylib      libgvplugin_gd.6.dylib          libgvplugin_neato_layout.6.dylib    libgvplugin_quartz.6.dylib      tcl
(python3) jespinozlt-osx:anaconda jespinoz$ pip install pygraphviz --install-option="--include-path=/usr/local/Cellar/graphviz/2.40.1/include/graphviz/" --install-option="--library-path=/usr/local/Cellar/graphviz/2.40.1/lib/graphviz"
/Users/jespinoz/anaconda/envs/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py:199: UserWarning: Disabling all use of wheels due to the use of --build-options / --global-options / --install-options.
  cmdoptions.check_install_build_global(options)
Collecting pygraphviz
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/98/bb/a32e33f7665b921c926209305dde66fe41003a4ad934b10efb7c1211a419/pygraphviz-1.3.1.tar.gz
Skipping bdist_wheel for pygraphviz, due to binaries being disabled for it.
mxnet 1.1.0 has requirement numpy<=1.13.3, but you'll have numpy 1.14.2 which is incompatible.
Installing collected packages: pygraphviz
  Running setup.py install for pygraphviz ... error
    Complete output from command /Users/jespinoz/anaconda/envs/python3/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/6z/5vbtz_gmkr76ftgc3149dvtr0003c0/T/pip-install-2d1lydtv/pygraphviz/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /private/var/folders/6z/5vbtz_gmkr76ftgc3149dvtr0003c0/T/pip-record-adm5qrum/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --include-path=/usr/local/Cellar/graphviz/2.40.1/include/graphviz/ --library-path=/usr/local/Cellar/graphviz/2.40.1/lib/graphviz:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/pygraphviz
    copying pygraphviz/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/pygraphviz
    copying pygraphviz/agraph.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/pygraphviz
    copying pygraphviz/graphviz.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/pygraphviz
    copying pygraphviz/release.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/pygraphviz
    copying pygraphviz/version.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/pygraphviz
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/pygraphviz/tests
    copying pygraphviz/tests/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/pygraphviz/tests
    copying pygraphviz/tests/test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/pygraphviz/tests
    copying pygraphviz/tests/test_attribute_defaults.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/pygraphviz/tests
    copying pygraphviz/tests/test_attributes.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/pygraphviz/tests
    copying pygraphviz/tests/test_clear.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/pygraphviz/tests
    copying pygraphviz/tests/test_drawing.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/pygraphviz/tests
    copying pygraphviz/tests/test_edge_attributes.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/pygraphviz/tests
    copying pygraphviz/tests/test_graph.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/pygraphviz/tests
    copying pygraphviz/tests/test_html.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/pygraphviz/tests
    copying pygraphviz/tests/test_layout.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/pygraphviz/tests
    copying pygraphviz/tests/test_node_attributes.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/pygraphviz/tests
    copying pygraphviz/tests/test_readwrite.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/pygraphviz/tests
    copying pygraphviz/tests/test_string.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/pygraphviz/tests
    copying pygraphviz/tests/test_subgraph.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/pygraphviz/tests
    copying pygraphviz/tests/test_unicode.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/pygraphviz/tests
    running egg_info
    writing pygraphviz.egg-info/PKG-INFO
    writing dependency_links to pygraphviz.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
    writing top-level names to pygraphviz.egg-info/top_level.txt
    reading manifest file 'pygraphviz.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*~' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '.svn' found anywhere in distribution
    no previously-included directories found matching 'doc/build'
    writing manifest file 'pygraphviz.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    copying pygraphviz/graphviz.i -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/pygraphviz
    copying pygraphviz/graphviz_wrap.c -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/pygraphviz
    running build_ext
    building 'pygraphviz._graphviz' extension
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/pygraphviz
    x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang -DNDEBUG -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -march=core2 -mtune=haswell -mssse3 -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fPIE -fstack-protector-strong -O2 -pipe -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -mmacosx-version-min=10.9 -I/usr/local/Cellar/graphviz/2.40.1/include/graphviz/ -I/Users/jespinoz/anaconda/envs/python3/include/python3.6m -c pygraphviz/graphviz_wrap.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/pygraphviz/graphviz_wrap.o
    pygraphviz/graphviz_wrap.c:2954:10: fatal error: 'graphviz/cgraph.h' file not found
    #include "graphviz/cgraph.h"
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    1 error generated.
    error: command 'x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/Users/jespinoz/anaconda/envs/python3/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/6z/5vbtz_gmkr76ftgc3149dvtr0003c0/T/pip-install-2d1lydtv/pygraphviz/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /private/var/folders/6z/5vbtz_gmkr76ftgc3149dvtr0003c0/T/pip-record-adm5qrum/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --include-path=/usr/local/Cellar/graphviz/2.40.1/include/graphviz/ --library-path=/usr/local/Cellar/graphviz/2.40.1/lib/graphviz" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/6z/5vbtz_gmkr76ftgc3149dvtr0003c0/T/pip-install-2d1lydtv/pygraphviz/
```

Comment: Do you have `~/anaconda/envs/py3_testing/include/graphviz/cgraph.h`? Try `pip install pygraphviz --install-option="--include-path=~/anaconda/envs/py3_testing/include" --install-option="--library-path=~/anaconda/envs/py3_testing/lib"` (no `graphviz` at the end).

Comment: It solved my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got it working:

```
# PyGraphViz
conda install graphviz --yes
pip download git+git://github.com/pygraphviz/pygraphviz.git#egg=pygraphviz
unzip pygraphviz*.zip
cd pygraphviz
python setup.py install --include-path=$CONDA_PREFIX/include --library-path=$CONDA_PREFIX/lib
pip install pydot
```

Comment: I trying doing that on MacOS. On second last line I got this error:

`python: can't open file 'setup.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory`

Comment: `phd`'s comment in the actual question, solved my problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

use the following command line (you need [homebrew](http://brewformulas.org/Graphviz)):

```
brew install graphviz
```